# Odd Highlighting of Questions with Favorite Tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, tags

I have [scrum](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrum), [agile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile), [unit-testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) and [tdd](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tdd) set as favorite tags. When I browse to [tdd](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tdd), I get two questions highlighted, followed by two not highlighted, followed by one highlighted, etc.

It looks like it's only highlighting questions which are in more than one of my favorite tags.

Answer (score 5):

When you click on a tag to view, it will not highlight questions with that tag.

The ones you have highlighted will also have other tags, such as  [scrum](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrum), [agile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agile) or [unit-testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) that is making them be highlighted as a favorite.

The ones that are not highlighted will only have [tdd](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tdd) from your list of favorites.

when you think about it, this makes sense. If it didn't behave this way, when you browse to one of your favorite tags everything would be highlighted, making highlighting useless.

Comment: I can't say that I like this. In order to understand the meaning of a highlighted question, I have to stop and remember that I'm in a special "mode". I think that highlighting should mean the same thing regardless of how I got to the display with the highlighted questions.

Comment: I disagree. I don't think it is unreasonable to assume that you know you have clicked on a tag. What advantage would highlighting every question give you? By doing that, you would be reducing the information on that page. The way it stands, if I click on a favorite tag, I can see which questions are my favorite for reasons other than that tag.

Comment: So, today I click on a tag, then go on vacation. I come back next week, and don't remember that I clicked on a tag. Or, I'm busy actually doing my job, and don't want to use the brain space to record the fact that I clicked on a tag.

Comment: I think there has to be a line drawn where edge cases become too small to worry about. Leaving a webpage open while on vacation then being slightly confused when you look at it a week later upon your return - I personally think that is on the wrong side of the line.

Comment: Sorry, just happened. But more importantly, it's an illustration of the general case of, "I shouldn't have to remember that I'm in a mode".

Comment: Oh, I'm not disagreeing that didn't happen. I'm disagreeing that it outweighs the negative. I'd say it currently is an example of the general case "I shouldn't put UI elements on a page that don't add something". Think of it as a Strunk & White "Every word should have a purpose" by for UI design. Besides, it takes 2 seconds to look at the URL to see you are in a 'search mode' and it took me maybe 10 seconds to work out what the highlighting did when I saw this Q. I don't think it is that hard.

Comment: I shouldn't need to look at the URL. I shouldn't need to look at a mode indicator. I should be able to glance at the page and see "this is a list of questions", and all "list of questions" should look and behave the same way.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: If you, for example, had [tag:waterfall] on your *ignored* list, but at some point visited that tag's page anyway -- would you want to see no question?

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer to see no questions, and a warning that my filters may have hidden them.